# Pyspark Joing using monthly range

Tags: pyspark

There are three tables A , B in Hive
A Table has the following columns and is Partitioned based upon Day. We need to extract data from 1st jan 2016 till 31st Dec 2016. I've just mentioned sample but these records are in millions for 1 year.

```
ID Day Name Description
1   2016-09-01  Sam   Retail
2   2016-01-28  Chris Retail
3   2016-02-06  ChrisTY Retail
4   2016-02-26  Christa Retail
3   2016-12-06  ChrisTu Retail
4   2016-12-31  Christi Retail
```

Table B

```
ID SkEY
1  1.1
2  1.2
3  1.3
```

Table C

```
Start_Date  End_Date Month_No
2016-01-01 2016-01-31 1
2016-02-01 2016-02-28 2
2016-03-01 2016-03-31 3
2016-04-01 2016-04-30 4
2016-05-01 2016-05-31 5
2016-06-01 2016-06-30 6
2016-07-01 2016-07-31 7
2016-08-01 2016-08-31 8
2016-09-01 2016-09-30 9
2016-10-01 2016-10-30 10
2016-11-01 2016-11-31 11
2016-12-01 2016-12-31 12
```

I've tried to write the code in spark but didn't work and resulting in a cartisa product on the join and performance was also very bad

```
Df_A=spark.sql("select * from A join B where a.day>=b.start_date
     and a.day<=b.end_date and b.month_no=(I)")
```

Actual Output should have the code in pyspark where A join B where every month needs to be processed. the value of I should automatically be incremented from 1 to 12 along with month dates. 
A Join B as shown above and A Join C using ID as well as performance should be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import sparksession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark import HiveContext
hiveContext= HiveContext(sc)


def UDF_df(i):
print(i[0])
ABC2=spark.sql("select * From A where day where day    
='{0}'.format(i[0]))
Join=ABC2.join(Tab2.join(ABC2.ID == Tab2.ID))\
.select(Tab2.skey,ABC2.Day,ABC2.Name,ABC2.Description)
Join\
 .select("Tab2.skey","ABC2.Day","ABC2.Name","ABC2.Description")
 .write\
 .mode("append")\
 .format("parquet')\
 .insertinto("Table")
ABC=spark.sql("select distinct day from A where day<= ' 2016-01-01' and day<='2016-
12-31'")
Tab2=spark.sql("select * from B where day is not null)
for in in ABC.collect():
UDF_df(i)

The following query is working but taking a long time as the number of  
columns are around 60(just used sample 3). Also didn't join Table C as I 
wasn't sure how to join to avoid cartisan join. performance isn't good, am 
not sure how to optimise the query.
```